# How to select multiple tables Spring Data JPA / Jhipster

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I get problem when select multiple table using Spring Data JPA, actually I use Jhipster.
I want to show result from this query 
"select c.id, c.city_name, s.name
from city c
left join student s on s.id = c.student_id"

but I always get error.
anyone please help me.

this is complete code.

CityResource

```
@GetMapping("/cities/{id}/try")
@Timed
public ResponseEntity<CityDTO> getCityLatihan(@PathVariable Long id) {
    log.debug("REST request to get City : {}", id);
    City city = cityRepository.findByIdTry(id);
    CityDTO cityDTO = cityMapper.toDto(city);
    return ResponseUtil.wrapOrNotFound(Optional.ofNullable(cityDTO));
}
```

CityRepository

```
public interface CityRepository extends JpaRepository<City,Long> {

@Query(value = "select c.id, c.city_name, s.name"
        + " from city c"
        + " left join student s on s.id = c.student_id"
        + " where c.id = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
City findByIdTry(Long id);}
```

Please anyone help me.

thanks.

Comment: You're doing it wrong if you are using JPA and still thinking in terms of tables first.  The whole point of JPA is to have SQL generated from objects so you can pretend that the relational model doesn't exist.

Comment: why are you joining student?

Comment: if you're trying to find a `City` by `id`, spring data already has a query method built for that.  `findOne(Long id)`.  You shouldn't have to write your own query

Comment: Could you post your exeception

Comment: Do the mapping and let JPA generate that SQL for you.  That's what the technology is for.

Comment: Don't forget to accept/upvote the answer if it helped you.. )

Answer (score 0):

How about this small correction? (method `findByIdTry` is no longer needed)

```
@GetMapping("/cities/{id}/try")
public ResponseEntity<CityDTO> getCityLatihan(@PathVariable Long id) {

    log.debug("REST request to get City : {}", id);
    City city = cityRepository.getOne(id);
    CityDTO cityDTO = cityMapper.toDto(city);
    return ResponseUtil.wrapOrNotFound(Optional.ofNullable(cityDTO));
}
```

---

Also instead of using 'DTO mapper' you can use a [projection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections) and get DTO **directly** from a repository:

```
public interface CityDto {

    Long getId();

    String getCityName();

    @Value("#{target.students}")
    List<Student> getStudents();

    @JsonProperty("studentNames")
    default List<String> getStudentNames() {
        return getStudents().stream().map(Student::getName).collect(Collectors.toList());
    } 
}

public interface CityRepository extends JpaRepository<City, Long> {

     Optional<CityDto> findById(Long id);
}

@GetMapping("/cities/{id}/try")
public ResponseEntity<?> getCityLatihan(@PathVariable Long id) {

    log.debug("REST request to get City : {}", id);

    return findById(id).map(dto -> ResponseEntity.ok().body(dto))
                       .orElse(new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND));
}
```